# PayPal custom button and radio options lead to error in processing transaction

Tags: html, css, paypal

I used the button creator from PayPal to generate a form with three fields: a dropdown selector with seven items and two text fields. I tried to customize it from table to divs, dropdown to radio buttons, one of the text inputs to textarea and making it float in two columns. It looks ok but now it returns an error page instead of going to PayPal checkout. Any guesses?

Here is the original code delivered from Paypal:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="6AC376J2R3286">
<table class="paypal">
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Escolha a box de presente">Escolha a box de presente</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
<option value="Original Mini" class="vezes">Original Mini R$59,00</option>
<option value="Original Normal">Original Normal R$99,00</option>
<option value="Original Familia">Original Familia R$159,00</option>
<option value="Superfoods Mini">Superfoods Mini R$59,00</option>
<option value="Superfoods Normal">Superfoods Normal R$99,00</option>
<option value="Kids">Kids R$69,00</option>
<option value="Sweet">Sweet R$69,00</option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Nome do presenteado">Nome do presenteado</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200"></td>    </tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Endereço completo (com CEP)">Endereço completo (com CEP)</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os2" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="BRL">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/pt_BR/BR/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - A maneira fácil e segura de enviar pagamentos online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/pt_BR/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

And this is the customized form:

```css
<style> div.colunaOpt {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.paypal_btn {
  font-family: "bree", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #512F2E;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #FFCF01;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
.paypal_btn:hover {
  background: #FDE24F;
}
.paypal {
  color: #512F2E;
  font-family: "bree", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
.vezes {
  color: #512F2E;
  font-family: "bree", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 2px;
}
.alimento {
  width: 224px;
  border-width: 1px;
  background: #E6D2C3;
  border-color: #512F2E;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #512F2E;
  font-family: "bree", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.cep {
  width: 224px;
  height: 70px;
  border-width: 1px;
  background: #E6D2C3;
  border-color: #512F2E;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #512F2E;
  font-family: "bree", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.centerBtn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="6AC376J2R3286" />
  <div class="colunaOpt">
    <div class="paypal">
      <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Escolha a box de presente" />Escolha a box de presente
    </div>
    <div>
      <input checked="checked" id="101" name="os0" type="radio" />
      <label value="Original Mini" for="101" class="vezes">Original Mini</label>
      <br/>
      <input id="102" name="os0" type="radio" />
      <label value="Original Normal" for="102" class="vezes">Original Normal</label>
      <br/>
      <input id="103" name="os0" type="radio" />
      <label value="Original Familia" for="103" class="vezes">Original Família</label>
      <br/>
      <input id="201" name="os0" type="radio" />
      <label value="Superfoods Mini" for="201" class="vezes">Superfoods Mini</label>
      <br/>
      <input id="202" name="os0" type="radio" />
      <label value="Superfoods Normal" for="202" class="vezes">Superfoods Normal</label>
      <br/>
      <input id="301" name="os0" type="radio" />
      <label value="Kids" for="301" class="vezes">Kids</label>
      <br/>
      <input id="401" name="os0" type="radio" />
      <label value="Sweet" for="401" class="vezes">Sweet</label>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="colunaOpt">
    <div class="paypal">
      <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Nome do presenteado" />Nome do presenteado</div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200" class="alimento" />
    </div>
    <div class="paypal">
      <input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Endereço completo (com CEP)" />Endereço completo (com CEP)</div>
    <div>
      <textarea name="os2" maxlength="900" class="cep"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="centerBtn">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="BRL" />
    <input type="submit" value="COMPRAR" name="submit" title="PayPal - A maneira fácil e segura de enviar pagamentos online!" class="paypal_btn" />
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/pt_BR/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
  </div>
</form>
```

I also added in [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/laisscortegagna/jueojbt3/2/) . I know it is probably simple, but I can't find the error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! In case anyone has similar issues here is the problem:
Instead of writting values inside labels they should be inside inputs.

**WRONG**

```
<input checked="checked" id="101" name="os0" type="radio"/>
<label value="Original Mini" for="101" class="vezes">Original Mini</label>
```

**RIGHT**

```
<input checked="checked" id="101" name="os0" value="Original Mini" type="radio"/>
<label for="101" class="vezes">Original Mini</label>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/laisscortegagna/jueojbt3/)